# Android Studio doesn't see Emulator (Not applicable for the main.dart configuration)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk

This is my first Flutter project. I set up an Emulator on Andoid Studio, but it doesn't see the device. At first it didnt even see the device on flutter doctor, then i came here and tried answers from different posts and now i can see the emulator on flutter doctor. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOm9k.png)

But on Android Studio it still says '' Not applicable for the main.dart configuration '' when i try running it.

I tried these: deleted the .idea file, checked google usb tools, made sure its the updated version (this is  3.7.1) ,selected the device from project structure, checked flutter plugins, added paths to system environments, re-opened the project. they didnt work. Please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTwml.jpg)

Comment: did you restart android studio? Apparently, you have made changes to the PATH, but in order for other applications to see them, they must be restarted.